# How to Determine IUSR Password

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have insatalled IIS version 8.5.9600.16384 .

My Anonymous Site Authentication was set to Specific User **"IUSR"** . I edited my Anonymous Authentication to Application Pool Identity . Again I need to Set my Anonymous authentication to Specific user . But for username **"IUSR"** it is asking for password .
I am getting like **"Specified password is invalid . Type a new password".**

can anyone help me please. 
Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Leave the password field blank and click OK.

Comment: Thanks a lot .. It Worked .

Comment: I get an error: `The specified password is invalid` (I am on version 10.0.18362.1)